# What update can be done to the Sub to begin copying at the header?

Tags: excel, copy

This Sub below copies a sheet from another sheet.  Teh length is variable so I have used LastRow.  I would like to update the Sub to not copy the whole sheet but copy from the header in wb2 to the last row of data.  The header display on  a different row each time.  The Column header in column "A" is "Client". The header in the last column is "Last"

Sub CopySheetsl_()

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro..xlsm")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("L:\ Report.xlsx")

 LastRow = wb2.Sheets("Page1_1").range("A:Y").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

 wb1.Sheets("Carrier").range("E1", "BU1" & LastRow) = wb2.Sheets("Page1_1").range("A1", "BQ1" & LastRow).value ' CopySht 'Range("A11", "I11" & LastRow).Value

 wb1.Close
 wb2.Close
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Range.CurrentRegion`

I'll edit this as it's tricky to read that code in the comment:

```
Sub test()
Dim strAddress As String

strAddress = Sheets(2).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address

Sheets(1).Range(strAddress) = Sheets(2).Range(strAddress).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried to use current region without any luck.  Where would I correctly add it in the Sub?  When i add it to the Sub runs without error but no data is moved.

Comment: I've not exactly copied your scenario but the following works in terms of copying current region: 

`Sub test()
Dim strAddress As String

strAddress = Sheets(2).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address

Sheets(1).Range(strAddress) = Sheets(2).Range(strAddress).Value
End Sub`

Comment: Still no luck.  I am not receiving a exception the SUb runs but no data is copied.  What am I missing?  Thanks for your help.